# CSS: issue with combo of style class set in the code vs applied by user action, want to restrict sub class

Tags: css

I have two types of styling to apply to links:

- links appearing in the body of the page will always have blue hover (the section uses "linkColors" class, like `<p class='contactInfo'>`)
- links appearing in the header have a different background color: they'll start with yellow hover when the page loads, then when the user scrolls down (and background goes away) we want blue hover like the others. (the section uses "Header-linkColors" class, and we have 'unscrolled' sub-class for different colors). I have javascript that adds/removes the class "unscrolled" depending on whether the user has scrolled.

My stylesheet has something like this:

```
.linkColors a:hover,
.linkColors a:focus {
  color: blue !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.Header-linkColors a:hover,
.Header-linkColors a:focus {
  color: blue !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}

  .unscrolled a:hover,
  .unscrolled a:focus {
    color: yellow !important;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

I apply the class names to paragraphs, like `<p class='contactInfo'>`, and as mentioned I have javascript that also applies the 'unscrolled' class based on user behavior to the top node: `<html class='unscrolled'>.`

I'd like the 'unscrolled' class to only apply when added to elements with the .Header-linkColors class and NOT the linkColors class. But with the code above that 'unscrolled' sub-class is taking effect even for links in the section using class "linkColors" (toward the top of the content, visible before any scrolling): they start with the yellow hover and only use blue hover only after I've scrolled. Inspecting the element from the browser, it has class "linkColors", as well as "unscrolled" as expected.

In another attempt I explicitly defined ".Header-linkColors .unscrolled" and ".linkColors .unscrolled" with their own hover colors, but when I inspected the elements in the UI those styles weren't being recognized (probably based on how 'unscrolled' gets applied differently). I'm new to CSS so I have a hunch I'm misunderstanding how this is supposed to work.

**What's the right way to keep the 'unscrolled' style to only take effect for links using the "Header-linkColors" class?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post your html code; the structure of the document is important in css.

What I think is happening: the space is an operator in css; it means you're selecting within elements that match the selector before it. By using it (`.class1 .class2`), you're selecting elements that have the second class within elements that have the first. **By ommitting it (**`.class1.class2`**), you're selecting elements that have both classes.**

```
.Header-linkColors.unscrolled a:hover,
.Header-linkColors.unscrolled a:focus {
  color: yellow !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

But I can be understanding your html wrong: for example, if `<a>` elements are the ones with all the classes, then you'd need `element.class1.class2:pseudoclass`.

Comment: Thanks, wordbug! I'd also tried defining the classes like .Header-linkColors.unscrolled and didn't get a match when inspecting the element, but I think your comments are on to the problem: 'unscrolled' is applied to the overall html, while "linkColors" or "Header-linkColors" is applied to the paragraph node, so the elements themselves don't have both. My problem is in there- not quite sure how to remedy it... will try the other order:  .unscrolled .Header-contactInfo

Comment: Confirmed! By changing the order and looking among the items with unscrolled class and then Header-linkColors class, now it works correctly, no more faulty edge cases. Thanks for describing what had been happening!

Comment: @DianeKaplan You're wellcome! this is my first Answer, glad I could help! :D